# Angular dart equivalent of anuglar js Otherwise for routing

Tags: routes, dart, angular-dart

I have been pretty comfortable setting up route in Angular.dart using RouteInitializerFn

But I have not been able to setup a '404' route.  That is when user visits an unmatched route, it should be redirected to a 404.html page.

```dart
  myRouter(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    view.configure({
      'home' : ngRoute(      
        defaultRoute : true,
        view : './home.html' // visiting www.mysite.com will load this view
      ),
      'user' : ngRoute(
        path : '/user',
        view : './user.html'
      ),
      'every-other-route' : ngRoute(
        path : '*', // apparently wildcard route matching doesn't work in angular
        view : '404.html'
      )
```

Any idea get every other route to load the 404.html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route that has the defaultRoute set to true (if any) is the one that will be matched when no other patterns match.

For your situation, you'd want to move the defaultRoute property from the 'home' route and into the 'every-other-route' route and remove the wildcard path from 'every-other-route' and likely give the home route a path.

That should leave you with something like:

```dart
myRouter(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
  view.configure({
    'home' : ngRoute(
       path: '/',
       view : './home.html' // visiting www.mysite.com will load this view
    ),
    'user' : ngRoute(
      path : '/user',
      view : './user.html'
    ),
    'every-other-route' : ngRoute(
      defaultRoute: true
      view : '404.html'
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: The only problem with using '/' as the home path is it won't work without pushState, I have this line as part of angular app module setup `value(NgRoutingUsePushState, new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));`